# If I update an RPM, do I have to rebuild all RPMs that are based on it

Tags: dependencies, rpm, rpm-spec

we have a series or RPMs that we build as part of our project with some being dependent on others. Say I have 3 RPMs A.rpm, B.rpm and C.RPM where both B and C depend on A, do I need to rebuild both everytime I update A? If I add a new feature to A to support a feature in B, but the code that is built to generate C has no idea about the new feature. Do I need to rebuild C against the updated A?

Or closer to my actual situation, I have an a library RPM that has about 25 RPMs that depend on it. We've added a new feature to the library to support an update in 1 of the RPMs, do I need to rebuild all other 24 RPMs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. There are two kind of dependencies: generated and implicit ones.

If you speak about C libraries, then rpmbuild generate dependencies like this:

```
$ rpm -R bash
...
libdl.so.2()(64bit)
...
```

And when the package which provides this library is updated, but it keeps the same [SONAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname), i.e., the same binary interface, then you do not need to rebuild the package which use it (in this example `bash`). But when there is SONAME bump and the package suddenly provides `libdl.so.3`, then you have to rebuild the package which requires it.

If the dependencies are something else, then you do not need to rebuild the package. For example package `firefox` requires `bash`, but it is fine with any version. So when `bash` is being updated, you do not need to rebuild `firefox`.

Sometime it happens that you depend on something (python-2.x) and it got very major upgrade (python-3.x), then you need to rebuild the package which requires it. In these rare cases you usually know about it in advance as you have to not only rebuild the package but rewrite the code of the application itself. E.g. migration from python2 to python3 is non-trivial.

*Quick'n'dirty tip for most case scenarios:* unless DNF/YUM tell you that you have broken dependencies, you do not need to rebuild your package.

Comment: follow-up question: so if package version/release goes from 1.1.3 to 1.1.4 does that resolve to an SONAME change? How about 1.1.3-1 to 1.1.3-2? Thanks

Comment: Change from  1.1.3-1 to 1.1.3-2 means that the package has the same tar file and there have been change only in spec file or patch has been added. So rebuild of packages which use this one is not needed.